# Hosting ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor Engine Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, shared-hosting

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC 3 beta Razor engine website. Its a small project. I would like to know if its possible to deploy Razor engine site to normal hosting provider. I assume I would need to copy relevant dll's to my site bin folder. Will this work or I would need to do something more than this to successfully deploy my site to shared hosting.

Comment: This link should help you:
http://blog.agafonov.net.ua/post/2010/11/02/Deploying-ASPNET-MVC-3-web-site.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 3 app to a web hoster that doesn't have it installed. The [link](http://blog.agafonov.net.ua/post/2010/11/02/Deploying-ASPNET-MVC-3-web-site.aspx) that tshao posted is a great start. The only requirement is that the hoster is running ASP.NET 4.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible to run MVC 3.0 with web pages inside shared hosting. please refer this article of mine;

[http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/deployment-of-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2-application-on-a-shared-hosting-environment-without-begging-the-hosting-company](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/39)